# react-native-immediate-phone-call not working

Tags: android, react-native, components, android-phone-call

I am writing app that uses `react-native-immediate-phone-call` and by pressing Pressable component I need to call function from that module.

```
import RNImmediatePhoneCall from 'react-native-immediate-phone-call';

export default function App() {
    const [getNumber, setNumber] = useState('');

    function makeCall() {
        console.log('dialing');
        return () => RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(getNumber);
    }
    ...
    return (
        ...
        <Pressable onPress={()=>makeCall()}>
            <Image source={require('./assets/phone-call.png')}/>
        </Pressable>
        ...
    );
}
```

Console log is displayed into terminal with Metro Bunler but return does not execute somehow. I am newbie into js and react.
How function and function call should like?

Comment: Try removing `() =>` from return statement `return RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(getNumber);`

Comment: Did not help, but console log still works. No exception is thrown so dependencies might be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that moment `getNumber == ''`

So, I think `RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall('')` do nothing.

Also, try with this (will be work when `getNumber` has a value)

```
function makeCall() {
    console.log('dialing');
    RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(getNumber);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Still, nothing happens, I find a solution from their issues

First, check your phone permission for call: In the *AndroidManifest.xml*
Then add the following lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

If still not working, do follow the steps

In *settings.gradle*
after `rootProject.name = 'YOUR_PROJ_NAME'`
add the following line

```
include ':react-native-immediate-phone-call', ':app'
```

In *build.gradle*
Inside the dependencies section insert the following line

```
implementation project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call')
```

In *AndroidManifest.xml*
add the following line with all other user-permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

In *MainActivity.java* import this

```
import com.github.wumke.RNImmediatePhoneCall.RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage;
```

inside the class, MainActivity add the following override
(include the "@override" for some reason it's not in the same block with the rest of the code)

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    
    RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); // very important event callback
    
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

}
```

Comment: Did not help. Am I doing something wrong with imported module? Am I supposed to create instance of `RNImmediatePhoneCall`?

Comment: @Kaldesyvon, I found the solution, it works for me fine. Please check and let me know

Comment: Yes. Instructions in "Edit" are helpful, it solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: @Kaldesyvon, You are welcome. Can you add `react-native-immediate-phone-call` also in tags? It will help someone find this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function but returning it so you get a function back.

Just change the following:

```
return () => RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(getNumber);
```

to:

```
RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(getNumber);
```